# Azure Indoor map on React-Native

Tags: azure, react-native, google-maps, maps, azure-maps

I showed azure map on a web portal but could not found any solution how to see it on a mobile device using React-Native. We do not want to use  web view for these problems. How do I show the azure map of mobile devices using react native. I have not found any library for showing Azure indoor maps on  mobile devices.

Please not use we view we required react native for azure map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indoor maps feature is currently only available in the Azure Maps Web SDK. Azure Maps does have native mobile SDK's, but these don't yet have the new indoor functionality, and they aren't React-Native libraries.

Comment: have you used indoor maps in a react web app? I am getting errors while trying to implement it.